# Using a parent class and the OO structure

Tags: c#, oop

I apologise for the abstract nature of this question (cannot post real code for business reasons) but I have inherited some code that I think is wrong in terms of structure and I would like someone to valid it is wrong. Some advice on how I can put it right, as my OO skills are not what they should be, would be brilliant.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Mynamespace
{
    public class TopClass
    {
        private MiddleClass middleClass;

        public TopClass()
        {
            this.middleClass = new MiddleClass();
        }

        public void SomeEventOccured()
        {
            BottomClass b = new BottomClass();
            this.middleClass.NewBottomClass(this, b);
        }
    }

    public class MiddleClass
    {
        private List<BottomClass> bottomClasses;

        public void NewBottomClass(TopClass topClass, BottomClass newBottomClass)
        {
            // Need some functionality on TopClass here or use of it other properties.
            // topClass.SomethingElse...

            bottomClasses.Add(newBottomClass);
        }
    }

    public class BottomClass
    {
        // Any old class structure
    }
}
```

The query is around the use of the parent class inside the middle class method, I think it is strange to pass the parent in to every call so the middle class can use methods on it. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

What we're thinking about doing to fix this is: use delegates and set these in bottom class to call into the top class in all areas where methods are executed.  Similarly, properties accessed in the top class will be exposed via simple delegate methods.  In our minds, this removes the circular ownership/referencing and replaces it with bi-directional communication between the objects. Thoughts?

Comment: I agree.

What is taken into account is cross referecing here, though not good style, still reached.
The usual way is to announce parent class objects via events.
A bad design, to pass parent objects to children, in order to access their members.

Comment: It's hard to give you good advice without knowing responsibilities of classes. But if you are passing `TopClass` to bottom class, then maybe your top class has some logic, which should exist in bottom class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define an [interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173156.aspx) like `IDoesWhatTopClassDoes` which the `TopClass` implements. This will allow the middle class to know that something which implements the interface exists, but not directly know what the `TopClass` is.

Then, to remove the need to be passing a reference every time, the `Middleclass` could hold a member reference to an `IDoesWhatTopClassDoes` instance passed in through the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Create a property on the Child class like so

```
public TopClass Parent {get;private set;}
```

Then set it in the constructor

```
public MiddleClass(TopClass parent)
{
    this.Parent = parent;
}

public TopClass()
{
   this.middleClass = new MiddleClass(this);
}
```

Then you can just use Parent inside the MiddleClass wihtout passing it in all the time.

Comment: I'd note that, while this does remove the need to pass the parent in every time, it is still not a great idea to be having a circular class dependency Top->Middle->Top.

Comment: Yes LlamaCloud, I agree and it is this reference we are trying to determine if we need and thus break. Is it called decoupling, or similar?